# pip does not work and cant be uninstalled

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I have problem with python package installer pip. When I try to install a package in Pycharm, I get following error:

> Error: Python packaging tool 'pip' not found

If I try install a package from terminal using pip, I get

```
      $ sudo pip install matplotlib
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg
/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg    /pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

I tried to uninstall pip by easy_install

```
$ sudo easy_install -mxN pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 7.1.0
Processing pip-7.1.0-py3.5.egg

Using /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.5.egg
Because this distribution was installed --multi-version, before you can
import modules from this package in an application, you will need to
'import pkg_resources' and then use a 'require()' call similar to one of
these examples, in order to select the desired version:
    pkg_resources.require("pip")  # latest installed version
    pkg_resources.require("pip==7.1.0")  # this exact version
    pkg_resources.require("pip>=7.1.0")  # this version or higher
```

and by pip

```
  $ sudo pip uninstall pip
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg
/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg    /pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

But files easy_install ; easy_install-3.5 ; f2py ; pip ; pip3 ; pip3.5 still remained in /usr/local/bin . I think these files prevent correctly reinstalling pip.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am using python 3.5
What should I do to install python packages?

**EDIT:**

After reinstalling python by:`sudo apt install python3-pip`

I still get error if try to install any package:

```
sudo pip install cairocffi
[sudo] password for olger: 
The directory '/home/olger/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/olger/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting cairocffi
  Downloading cairocffi-0.7.2.tar.gz (75kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 491kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
        extra_postargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
        spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
        _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
        % (cmd, exit_status))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 160, in run
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 146, in call_command
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 10, in run
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 49, in run
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 338, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 447, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 472, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 174, in build_extension
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 532, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
        self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
        raise CompileError(msg)
    distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 152, in save_modules
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 237, in run_setup
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 267, in run
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 236, in runner
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
      File "/tmp/easy_install-zlcvz3si/cffi-1.7.0/setup.py", line 192, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1056, in run_setup
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 240, in run_setup
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 164, in save_modules
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 139, in resume
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/compat.py", line 65, in reraise
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 152, in save_modules
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 237, in run_setup
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 267, in run
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 236, in runner
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
      File "/tmp/easy_install-zlcvz3si/cffi-1.7.0/setup.py", line 192, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-u6rhv636/cairocffi/setup.py", line 65, in <module>
        **cffi_args
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 836, in resolve
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1081, in best_match
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1093, in obtain
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 629, in easy_install
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in install_item
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 842, in install_eggs
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1070, in build_and_install
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1058, in run_setup
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-u6rhv636/cairocffi/
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

**EDIT 2:**
Another interesting thing is that, if I try to run any PIP command, I get:

```
$ pip show pycairo
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

but if I check version of PIP, I get:

```
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /home/olger/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Maybe it is because last version of pip is not correctly uninsatlled.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install python3-pip` instead.

Comment: I tried it, but got another error:
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-u6rhv636/cairocffi/

Comment: That is a pretty useless warning and there are probably more useful error messages that come before this one.

Comment: It says that current user is not owner of directory, but I am only user of my computer.

Comment: Should I delete the files, that remained after uninstalling pip?

Comment: This is getting too long and probably off-topic too. You should ask this question on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).